# Except the input check box i need to disable all other input using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('fieldset').not('#Pchk input[type=checkbox]').find("input,select,textarea").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Pchk is the id of my input checkbox

and even i did this code to its not working out for me..

```
$('fieldset').not(':checkbox').find("input,select,textarea").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

if I use this code its disabling even my checkbox from fieldset? this code is right?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `.not()` as the second part of the chain because:

> .not( selector ) Returns: jQuery
>
> Description: Remove elements from the
>   set of matched elements.

and you're trying to match fieldsets in the first order ;)

try:

```
$('fieldset').children("input,select,textarea").not('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the not filter to the fieldset, not to the inputs. Try:

```
$('fieldset').find('input:not(:checkbox),select,textarea').attr('disabled','disabled');
```